# How to add a background image in html?

Tags: html, background

```
<div id="header" style="background-image:"URL of file?">
    <h1 style="margin-bottom:15;text-align:center;">
        <font face="Lucida Calligraphy">
             <u>Text to be displayed</u>
        </font>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Please help as to what kind of line must be written to get a background for the header container.

Answer (score 3):

You should use CSS for your styling. The `<font>` tag which you use is deprecated. You should also be using the HTML5 `header` tag.

Have your HTML as only the markup:

```
<header>
    <h1>Text to be displayed</h1>
</header>
```

And this CSS for styling:

```
header{
    background-image:url('url of file');
}

h1{
    margin-bottom:15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Lucida Calligraphy', sans-serif;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the background image of html elements using the background css attribute.

**.css**

```
 /*[Option A]*/
 html { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg); 
 }

 /*Or if you have a, or want to use a class*/

 /*[Option B]*/
 .someClass { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg); 
 }
```

then to implement

**.html**

```
   <!--[If you use Option A]-->
   <html></html>

   <!--[If you use Option B]-->
   <div class="someClass"></div>
```

both options can be applied to almost any element.

> Some more info on the [topic](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3868361)